# Using a single front camera, how to filter out cars which are not in the same path, without visible lane markings?

Tags: computer-vision

I would like to compute time-to-collision to the closest in-path vehicle using a single front-facing camera. I have detected all the vehicles in the scene and obtained their 2D bounding boxes. I need to filter out all the cars which are not in the same path (or lane) and then consider the closest car with the biggest bounding box as my target vehicle to compute time-to-collision. Now my problem is without clear lane markings, I don’t know how to filter out the cars which are not in the same lane. I have tried simple methods like cars which their bounding box include the camera center point, are in-path vehicles, but this assumption is very naive and will have lots of false positives. Also we don’t have camera calibration. Any comment and suggestion would be much appreciated.

Please see an example below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tMD0.jpg)

Comment: Please try to narrow your question down to something more specific. Show us what you've tried and with what sample data, and how the actual result differs from your expectations.

Comment: May be to use machine learning? For example, to train network to predict cars that are in different angles of view, so in combination with the center point you mentioned it might work (just an idea).